# In the Django admin interface, is there a way to check a few list items and trigger an action to copy field contents to clipboard?

Tags: django, django-admin, clipboard

For example, if I had a model: StoragePosition(models.Model) which has a field, 'name'.

I would want to enter the model's list/change view. Then select a few items, choose a 'copy names to clipboard' action. Then be able to paste in the format:

```
name_1
name_2
name_3
```

I would especially want it to be able to paste contents into an excel spreadsheet, each name in its own cell.

Comment: With javascript, sure. Select row and exec `document.execCommand("copy");`

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple solution to the actual problem by using no external dependencies and no javascript.

I really just wanted a view with the information I required on its own, listed one beneath the other.

---

In admin.py:

```
def copy_selection_to_clipboard(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    return HttpResponse("<br>".join([str(q) for q in queryset]))


copy_selection_to_clipboard.short_description = 'Copy selection to clipboard'
```

In MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

```
...
    actions = (copy_selection_to_clipboard,)
...
```

I am yet to test @martin-stoyanov's answer out, so won't mark this as accepted answer yet. Also, unlikely to be marked as such since it provides a workaround to the problem and not a direct solution to it.

Answer (score -1):

Check [Pyperclip](https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/).

You can define your own main action in model's list by doing:

```
import pyperclip
def copy_selected_to_clipboard(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    #pyperclip code example
    pyperclip.copy('The text to be copied to the clipboard.')
    #or whatever logic you need.
```

Then include it in your **ModelAdmin** class as following:

```
MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = ['copy_selected_to_clipboard', ] // <-- include list function here
```

Comment: Wouldn't this copy to the server's clipboard?

Comment: It should copy it to your current OS's clipboard as it is cross-platform.

Comment: uh...I don't think pyperclip transpiles python code to JS/HTML, it would copy it to the server's clipboard.